# Chess Question combinations

Tags: combinations

I would like to place atleast 2 white queens and atleast 2 black coins on a 5×5  chessboard,such that queens on either side cannot attack the opposing queens.
What is the maximum no. of coins which can be placed on the board satisfying the stated constraint?

Comment: I did 5. Who can do better ?

Comment: You could write a small program to find the solution

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a small program to test all the possibilities and it appears that 7 is the maximum. Queens positions are B1 and E2

Comment: consider queens on A1 and B1. Then you can place 6 more opposite coloured Queens at C4, C5, D2, D5, E2, E3.

Comment: I am not counting the white queens so 9 is the maximum number of total coins